# MySQL Call: Complete orders with a subset of products

Tags: mysql

The problem we have is the following. We have a shop_orders database with orders placed by customers:

```
Id | User_id
-------------
1  |       1
```

On the other hand we have the table shop_order_products, which contains the products that contain each order, where the field order_id relates both tables:

```
ID | Order_id | Qty | Product_id | Product_name | Product_price |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1  |        1 |   2 |         23 |   Samsung S5 |          40.5 |
2  |        1 |   1 |         12 |    IPhone 6S |            80 |
```

Just to clarify, in this example order 1 has 2 units of Samsung and 1 unit of iPhone.

We are able to know, through the table shop_order_products, which are the best selling products of our online store, by calling:

```
SELECT *, COUNT (*) sales FROM shop_order_products GROUP BY order_id ORDER BY sales DESC
```

We need, given a subset of products, to know how many COMPLETE orders we could get. That is, if we had the products we sell the most are the iPhone 6S and Samsung Galaxy S5, how many full orders we would take with those two products. If an order contains both products but also others, it would not be taken into account for our calculation.

Comment: The query you are showing is incorrect. You are not selecting the best selling products, but the orders with the highest number of entries in shop_order_products. For each order you show one of their records arbitrarily chosen, i.e. which products are shown in your results is a matter of chance.

Comment: Here is a query to get products orderd by sales: `select product_id, product_name, sum(qty) as sales from shop_order_products group by product_id order by sum(qty) desc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want orders that *only* have a given set of products and no others.  Also, you don't seem to be taking quantity into account.

So:

```
select sop.order_id
from shop_order_products sop
group by sop.order_id
having sum(sop.product_id in (<your list here>)) = count(*);
```

The `sum()` counts the number of rows (for each order) that have an acceptable product.  The `= count(*)` specifies that this is all rows.